# how to update date and time in textview which is in listview for messages each time

Tags: textview, android

```
GregorianCalendar calCreationDate = new GregorianCalendar(); 

int intMilli = calCreationDate.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND); 

int intSeconds = calCreationDate.get(Calendar.SECOND); 

calCreationDate.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (-1*intMilli)); 

calCreationDate.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1*intSeconds); 

calCreationDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); 


Date dateStartDate = calCreationDate.getTime();

String time =dateStartDate.toString();
```

Comment: What/where exact is your issue?

Comment: Actually i am doing smschat Application,which can stores a messages in list view,but i want to set the date & time for each & every message.i set the the date & time,but it showing current time that is when last message was sent,that time only updated to all the messages... so plz help me to set the date & time for each & every message with update time....

Comment: Am developing SMSCha Appication,which stores a list of messages in listview,actually i want to update date and time for each message which is in listview,i had set the date & time by using above code,but it showing current date & time to all messages in listview,it's not updating date & time foe every time for each message